# Gstreamer either getting high CPU or returning older frames

Tags: python, video, cpu, gstreamer

I am trying to decode several video streams using GStreamer and Python. Here's my code:

```
self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if self.video_capture.isOpened() is False:
    raise Error
while True:
    status, image = self.video_capture.read()
    # do slow stuff
```

I am encountering the following issue:

*Option 1*

If I use the pipeline:

```
self.pipeline = f"rtspsrc location={self.url} latency=10 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=1 drop=true"
```

I get extremely high CPU consumption. Also, I am probably decoding more frames than the number my application can actually consumes.

*Option 2*

If I use this pipeline

```
self.pipeline = f"rtspsrc location={self.url} latency=10 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=1 drop=false"
```

After a few hours the application is returning me old frames. E.g. at 9am my application was receiving frames at nighttime (from the night before).

Is this the expected behavior? How can I solve this problem?

Thank you a lot

Comment: did you find out why drop=true increases cpu load?

Comment: I added an answer below. Let me know if that helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With `drop=true` we decode all the frames and we drop them only after decoding them
- Probably best solution would be to use both `latency=10` and `drop=true` when using software decoders (this could cause corrupted frames with hardware decoders)